# Browser cache expires correctly with Chrome, but not with Firefox or IE9

Tags: caching, browser, cache-control

I have searched for answers to this problem, but most questions seem to be the reverse of mine, i.e., cache does not work at all in other questions. My problem is that Chrome handles image caching as expected, but Firefox and IE9 appear to cache forever, even though told to only cache for 2 minutes.

I am generating images and returning to browser with both **Expires** and **Cache-Control: max-age** headers. I am not setting **Last-Modified** header. Testing with Chrome version 23, Firefox version 11 (Linux) and Firefox version 16 (Windows) and IE9.

Watching HTTP responses, all three browsers fetch image and show correct expiration times (2 minutes in the future). All show response=200.

Next I use javascript to change the IMG SRC. More HTTP response=200. When I return to a previously fetched image, there is no request to server - it is loaded from browser cache. This is correct with all 4 browsers.

Wait more than 2 minutes and try again. Chrome makes request to server and receives image back with HTTP response=200. This is what I expect.

But neither Firefox or IE9 will ever again request the image from server.
If I clear the browser cache (using tools, not shift-reload), Firefox will then reload, but IE9 *still* will not reload. OK, we already know how lame IE9 is.

I sure hope I don't get shredded for not discovering that this has already been answered.

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can look?

Comment: I've never used fiddle, but I understand it a bit and don't see how it is relevant to my problem. Basically I'm seeing that different browsers handle image caching directives differently and only Chrome seems to be correct; can fiddle help me debug a browser problem? I'm looking for commentary from people who know browsers and HTTP far better than me.

Comment: With a fiddle, we can see the _exact_ HTTP headers you're sending, as well as do _some_ testing. If you provide a bare URL for the image, we can do some testing as well; can you provide the image URL?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide image URL - authorized access only - client SSL authentication is required.